# how to import excel file into angular project typescript

Tags: html, angular, excel, typescript, import

In my Angular project I have an excel file with this informations (FirstName, LastName, Age, Date), so I create a function making me to export this data format excel. now I need to create a function making me to import excel file into my angular project (add information of excel file in the table).

this is my code :

**clients.html :**

```
<div class="panel-body table-responsive">
    <table id="excel-table" class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>FirstName</th>
                <th>LastName</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor='let client of clients'>
                <td>{{client.FirstName}}</td>
                <td>{{client.LastName}}</td>
                <td>{{client.Age}}</td>
                <td>{{client.Date}}</td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" (click)="exportexcel()">ExportExcel</button>

     <div class="upload-btn-wrapper">
     <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="importexcel()">Importer Excel</button>
     <input type="file" name="myfile" />
     </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**clients.ts :**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-clients',
  templateUrl: './clients.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./clients.component.css']
})
export class ClientsComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor() { }

  fileName = 'ExcelFile.xlsx';

  exportexcel(): void {
    const data = this.clients.map(c => ({ 'LastName': c.LastName, 'Age': c.Age }));
    const ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(data);
    const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'Sheet1');
    XLSX.writeFile(wb, this.fileName);
  }

importexcel(): void {}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx#parsing-workbooks):

Starting with an HTML INPUT element with type="file":

```
<input type="file" id="input_dom_element">
```

For modern websites targeting Chrome 76+, Blob#arrayBuffer is recommended:

```
async function handleFileAsync(e) {
  const file = e.target.files[0];
  const data = await file.arrayBuffer();
  /* data is an ArrayBuffer */
  const workbook = XLSX.read(data);

  /* DO SOMETHING WITH workbook HERE */
}
input_dom_element.addEventListener("change", handleFileAsync, false);
```